# How to extract a string from string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to extract a string from string, I use a table and it has dynamic strings continuously update, I would like to extract the last string.

I've tried to use `CHARINDEX`, `PATINDEX`, `SUBSTRING`, but the length of the string isn't fixed. Probably the only alternative is to identify the number and then to extract the next string. Does anybody have a suggestion?

```
Hector Maya           Supervisión  4  Coecillo
Bulmaro Vieyra        Supervisión  1  Coecillo
Bulmaro Vieyra        Supervisión  1  Coecillo
Edgar Salgado         Supervisión  2  Coecillo
José A Castillo       Supervisión  5  Coecillo
Bulmaro Vieyra        Supervisión  1  Coecillo
Marco Martin Ortiz H. Supervisión  3  Oriente León
Arturo Salazar L.     Supervisión  2  Oriente León
Nancy Pérez G.        Supervisión  4  Oriente León
Arturo Salazar L.     Supervisión  2  Oriente León
```

What I want the last word:

'Coecillo', 'Oriente León', etc

Comment: what is your rdbms? Sql server, postgres?

Comment: Your given example has no clear output!

Comment: Are they separated by tabs? Simply reverse the string, find first (last in un-reversed string) tab, gets its location, un-reverse string and take everything after its position

Comment: Thanks to answer! is SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Are separated only by tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `patindex()` and `reverse()` to take the `right()` part of the string after the last number.

```
select LastPart = ltrim(rtrim(right(col,patindex('%[0-9]%',reverse(col))-1)))
from t
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/TLE45990

returns:

```
+--------------+
|   LastPart   |
+--------------+
| Coecillo     |
| Coecillo     |
| Coecillo     |
| Coecillo     |
| Coecillo     |
| Coecillo     |
| Oriente León |
| Oriente León |
| Oriente León |
| Oriente León |
+--------------+
```

Comment: Hello Zim. do you show me a different rextester the other day? Didnt save the link.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza http://dbfiddle.uk  e.g. http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=be40ff7427fe50c19300652d0915990f

Comment: Excellent!!! Thanks to anybody! It's the solution!!!!